# Matlab: How to 'cd' (change directory) to a folder with name as num2str(#number)?

Tags: matlab, mkdir, cd

I have a loop and in each iteration I create a directory with the iteration name and I copy some files inside that folder and afterwards I want to `cd` to that folder, but when I want to `cd`, I get the error as

"Error using cd
Cannot CD to num2str(i) (Name is
nonexistent or not a directory)."

How can I fix this issue?

```
parfor i=1:20000
    iter=num2str(i);
    mkdir(iter)
    copyfile('./mainfolder',iter)
    cd ./num2str(i)
    [pow_maxx,FFee,AA33,BB33,shape] = main(i);
    power_max(i,:)=pow_maxx(1,:);
    Fe(i,:)=FFee;
    A3(i,:)=AA33;
    B3(i,:)=BB33;  
    Shape_all(i,:)=shape(1,:);  
end
```

Comment: `./num2str(i)` is not valid Matlab. Try something like `cd(['./' num2str(i)])` (or maybe just `cd(num2str(i))`).

Comment: Thanks it works this way

Comment: @horchler I have a similar problem with removing directory.
1. How can one remove a directory which its name is a number which has been turned into str as `num2str(20)` for instance.

None of the below worked:

    `rmdir(num2str(20));`
    `rmdir('num2str(20)');`
    `rmdir(20);`
    `rmdir('20');`

2. And how one can delete only the contents of the folder named as `num2str(20)`

Comment: Please read the help/documentation for `rmdir`. If the directory is not empty, you need to use a second argument, e.g., `rmdir(num2str(20),'s')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code `cd ./num2str(i)`, `./num2str(i)` is not a string, just use `cd ['./',num2str(i)]`.

What's more, if you have some string `str1='abc'` and `str2='def'`, you can use `[str1,str2]` to concat them.